# How to create inliers inside a synthetic high dimensional dataset?

Tags: distributions, high-dimensional

Since inliers have different definitions in different papers, the one I'm using is: *"An inlier is a data value that lies in the interior of a statistical distribution and is in error."*

An example of inliers would be points inside a sphere in 3D(which can be generated with a uniform distribution of numbers.) Illustration:

[image: Inliers]

If you look carefully there are two points in the center of the sphere. Those are the inliers.

My question is, how to create such inliers in higher dimensions, such as a hypersphere in 5D? What would the coordinates of an inlier be in such case?

**Edit** to clarify  @user20160:

How I generate the distribution for the 3d-sphere (works same way with higher dimensional spheres):

```
for i in range(0,500):
    v = [0, 0, 0]

    while np.linalg.norm(v) < .0001:
        x = np.random.randn() 
        y = np.random.randn()
        z = np.random.randn()
        v = [x, y, z]

    v = v / np.linalg.norm(v)
```

Comment: According to your definition, an inlier is any point $x$ where $\|x -c\| < r$ where $c$ is the center of the hypersphere and $r$ is its radius. If you want a way to sample these points, you'd first have to pick a distribution to sample from.

Comment: @user20160 I generate the points on a hypersphere(3+Dimensions) by first generating standard normally distributed numbers which form a vector. After normalizing the vector it will lie on the sphere.

Comment: @user20160 But I am not restricting the question to hyperspheres only. It can apply to other manifolds as well, like a hypercube

Comment: What I mean is that you'd need to specify a distribution for the inliers. Any distribution whose support lies within the boundaries is valid. But, for any choice of boundary, there are infinitely many such distributions, and you'd have to pick one to sample from. For example, do you want the uniform distribution on the interior of the the hypersphere/cube/etc.?

Comment: @user20160 ah yes, the distribution would be in the interior of the hypersphere, not just within its boundaries. Sorry I didn't understand earlier

Comment: So, do you want the uniform distribution on the interior or something else? Also: 1) Do you want the boundary to be defined by some closed-form expression, or by points sampled on the boundary? 2) Are there any useful constraints on the shape? For example, is it convex?

Comment: @user20160 yes, interior of the n-sphere, close it to its center. Shape doesn't matter

Comment: I think the difficulty would be in defining the interior of a distribution in a general case -- for example, what should the algorithm return if we run it on a uniform distribution in n-dims? How about a distribution shaped like a hollow cylinder with no end caps -- does that have a well defined interior? What about a high-dimensional gaussian, where [most of the mass is located in a thin shell](https://ontopo.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/reasoning-in-higher-dimensions-measure/) (a sphere in the isotropic case), but the density is highest in the center? As it is, the question seems poorly defined.

Comment: @shimao then I would restrict the uniform distribution to just an [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on: "*An inlier is a data value that lies in the interior of a statistical distribution and is in error.*" On the one hand, you seem to be saying it is just a data value within a restricted region of the sample space generated by a given distribution; on the other: "*...only the two points in the center of the sphere -- those are the inliers.*"

Comment: @Jim the two inliers are in the interior of the uniformly distributed points of the sphere, specifically near to its center. That goes with the definition that I provided

Comment: Couple of points to consider... *1)* You write "*generated with a uniform distribution of numbers*" yet in your code you use `randn()` which implies a standard normal distribution. *2)* Could you color the "inliers" with a different color than blue (that would seriously improve the clarity of your question!) *3)* When you say uniformly distributed: what do you mean? Uniform on the surface of the sphere? Because it **surely** is not uniform in $[-1,1] \times [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$.